# objective-c post data & image

Tags: objective-c, post, asihttprequest, afnetworking

I am new to objective-c and I have been searching for a way to send a post request to my server (based on Rest URL) but also include an image with it... I have found many methods to post data... and methods to post just an image, but nothing that combines the two...

I am searching for a wrapper, class or library because it seems to be a tedious task to write all this from scratch. I found the "ASIHTTPRequest" but this is no longer supported, although Ic an turn off ARC, I would prefer to find something still supported...

I also found AFNetworking, which seems to still be supported but I could be wrong, I just cannot find a solution to combine VERY simply data and a profile image...

Any help is appreciated?

Should I just use the ASIHTTPRequest library... ?? Or does anyone have any sample code for the AFNetworking library?

Here is the code I am using for AFnetworking library...

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        _emailAddressField.text, @"email",
                        _usernameField.text, @"username",
                        _passwordField.text, @"password",
                        nil];

AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:%"http://url.com/api/whatever/"];

[client postPath:@"/" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{

    NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", text);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{

    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AFNetworking, you can use `multipartFormRequestWithMethod` to upload an image:

```
// Create the http client
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseUrl:url];
// Set parameters
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"param1", @"key1", nil];
// Create the request with the image data and file name, mime type, etc.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:method path:@"url/to/" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:nameData fileName:fileName mimeType:mimeType];
}];
```

And then you can add the upload progress block to get feedback of the upload process:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    //Manage upload percentage
}];
```

Also, you can add `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess` to catch success and failure in your operation. More info can be found [here](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/). At last but not least important, add the request to the operation queue:

```
[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```